# Inconsistent Computation Times

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm attempting to count the number of rows in a very large csv file (~2GB).  The bizarre thing is that when the command `wc -l my_file.csv`.  It takes a very long time.   However, if I re-run the same code again, it take much less time.

I have timed this phenomena.  When I run `wc` the first time.

```
real 12m30.120s
user 0m1.226s
sys 0m2.523s
```

When I run `wc` a second time.

```
real 0m1.428s
user 0m1.203s
sys 0m0.196s
```

From my primitive understanding of how computers actually work, I understand that if the `real` > `user` + `sys` the something weird is going on. Does anyone have an idea what is going on.

I'm on a iMac with plenty of RAM (16GB)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the file is already cached when you run it second time.

Comment: Perhaps it would improve the answer a bit to mention that by "cache" here you mean in RAM and reading from RAM is much faster than disk.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense.  Is there any way to speed up this process of transferring this information from disk to RAM?

Comment: The reason why there was such a large difference between `real` and `sys + user` is that my data was on a network and was not installed locally on my machine.